# How deal with separate dependencies in libgdx?

Tags: gradle, libgdx, dependencies

I wonder about dependencies in `libgdx`. Each sub project (Android, iOS etc) can have their own dependencies as I understand it (they have their own build`.gradle` file).

I thought that I would only import a dependency to for example the core-project and then all the other sub projects would use that dependency also. Is that not the case? Or do I always need to specify a dependency many times for each sub project, even though I imported it already in the core project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In libgdx, every projects depends on the core project, so if the core project depends on a library the subproject will depend on it as well.

You can easily manage dependencies in gradle with [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile "group.name:artifactId:versionX"  
}
```

Filled in for libgdx this would make:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:1.4.1"
}
```

To add more dependencies add another `compile ""` on a new line.